# how to add string text rowsPerPageOptions in mui Table Pagination?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Anyone can help me ? please check the below image i want to change the 10 from to 10 page per.
whenever i select 10 20 or 30 i want to get something like 20 per page 30 per page .
[image: please check image one]

This below image is the example of what actually i want.
[image: please check image two]

guys i have read the whole table pagination api documentation but i couldnt get it.
[image: please check the image three]

please check the code snapshot now.
[image]

[image]

Comment: anyone can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the [docs](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/table-pagination/#main-content), the `rowsPerPageOptions` can handle an array of objects

`rowsPerPageOptions Array<number | { label: string, value: number }>`

means u can use like:

```
...
count={10}
rowsPerPageOptions={[
   { label: "10 per page", value: 10 },
   { label: "20 per page", value: 20 },
]}
rowsPerPage={rowsPerPage}
...
```

Comment: wao thanks my friend . its working like charm.

Comment: This is exaclty what i want to do but i can't make it work, how did you do it ? Can you post your solution please ? (a little stackblitz maybe)

Comment: This may or may not be your issue, but in the more recent versions of @mui, it seems the value HAS to be a string, e.g., this would work:  { label: "10", value: 10 }, but this would not:  { label: 20, value: 20 }.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to add Ids on the options, for testing so I did this, which perfectly works.

```
<TablePagination>
  ...
  rowsPerPageOptions={[
    { label: <span id="option-1">10</span>, value: 10 },
    { label: <span id="option-2">20</span>, value: 20 },
  ]}
```

But it throws me a warning : "
Invalid prop `rowsPerPageOptions[0]` supplied to `ForwardRef(TablePagination)`, expected one of type [number, string]."
Which I don't know how to resolve yet.

[image]